# Xamarin Form Android Bluetooth Service discovery failed

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.forms

I have an app written in Xamarin Form that connects to a Bluetooth device (not LE).
The code for Bluetooth is written in a DepencedyService.
Some users (minus of 0.1 % ) have said that they get this message : "OS/Service discovery failed"

The function that displays the message is:

```
public bool OpenSocket(string xxxDevice)
    {
        bool rVal = false;
        try
        {
            device = (from bd in adapter.BondedDevices
                      where bd.Address == xxxDevice
                      select bd).FirstOrDefault();
            if (device == null)
                return false;
            _socket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
            _socket.Connect();
            rVal = true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<BTCode, string>(this, "Bluetooth", "OS/" + ex.Message);
        }
        return rVal;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: What was the end result of this?

Comment: Hi, the problem I have not solved yet